# From RichTextBox to text files, line after line

Tags: c#, text, save, richtextbox

I have trouble with saving file from Richtextbox to text file.

My richtextbox looks like this;

```
ABC    ...
 SDE   ...
KLO    ...
```

After i saved it looks like this:

```
ABC ... SDE ... KLO ...
```

But i want the same like richtextbox line after lines. What did i do wrong?

```
 if (saveFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(saveFileDialog2.FileName);
            sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();

            //File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog2.FileName, str);
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably getting this because you are trying to save `richTextBox1.Text` (the whole text) in one line only using the following code

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(saveFileDialog2.FileName);
sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

It's recommended to use `sw.WriteLine()` on a specific line number in `richTextBox1` then move to another line.

**Example**

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
}
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

### **Another Solution**

---

There's already a built-in function for `RichTextBox` to save a file with a specific encoding. You may use `RichTextBox.SaveFile()` for this purpose.

**Example**

```
RichTextBox.SaveFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType);
```

Where `path` represents `saveFileDialog2.FileName` in your code. For `RichTextBoxStreamType`, it's best to set it as `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` as long as you do not use RTF such as Color/Font/Protection/Indent/etc...

Then, you may read the file again using the following method

```
RichTextBox.LoadFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType);
```

**NOTICE:** If the file is not in RTF and you try to read it in RTF (`RichTextBox.LoadFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);`)
 you may encounter formatting errors. In this case, you'll need to catch the exception and read the file in a Plain or Unicode encoding.

**Example**

```
RichTextBox _RichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
try
{
     _RichTextBox.LoadFile(@"D:\Resources\text.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
     if (EX.Message.ToLower().Contains("format is not valid"))
     {
          _RichTextBox.LoadFile(@"D:\Resources\text.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
     }
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is pretty old but here is an alternate code for people who might run into this problem in the future

`File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Lines);`

Comment: Thanks. It solves my problem for converting new line characters.

Comment: Avoid using `WriteAllLines` ,if u have a better option, as it's blocking in nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (saveFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(saveFileDialog2.FileName);
    foreach(String s in richTextBox1.Lines)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(s);
    }
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: it gives me `ABC ...  SDE ...` then another line `KLO ...`  and it still not what i want. what is here wrong?