# WriteLine to .txt for each line in richTextBox

Tags: c#

Hello I have this line of code to write every line of richTextBox into my .txt file but at the final the txt file is empty but when debug it reads every line. May I know how this code should be improved to do what I want?

```
                string Path = (@"C:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MTest\txtCmdLog.txt");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path, System.IO.FileMode.Append));

            for (int i = 0; i <= txtCmdLog.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                 sw.WriteLine(txtCmdLog.Lines[i] + "\n");

            }

            sw.Close();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Improved? You said it wasn't working? anyway: for (int i = 0; i < txtCmdLog.Lines.Length; i++)

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251536/from-richtextbox-to-text-files-line-after-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtCmdLog.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(txtCmdLog.Lines[i]);
}
```

Don't use `<=` in the loop's condition check.  You also don't need to append a newline character in the call to WriteLine, since that method already writes a newline.

Answer (score 2):

**Points to remember:**

1.you need to loop through `0` to `lines.Length-1`.so remove `=` in `<=` condition.

2.for disposing the `StreamWriter` object use `using{}` block so that you don't need to call `close()`.
`Diposal` of StreamWriter object will be taken care by `using {}` block

```
        string Path = (@"C:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MTest\txtCmdLog.txt");
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path, System.IO.FileMode.Append)))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txtCmdLog.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                 sw.WriteLine(txtCmdLog.Lines[i] + "\n");

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, arrayOfStrings);
```