# How to fill datagridview a "-" delimited text from a richtextbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, delimiter

How can i fill my datagridview with a - delimited text from my richtextbox?

example:

my richtextbox content:

```
000001-Kobe-Bryant-24-Lakers

000002-Lebron-James-23-Cavaliers

000003-Derick-Rose-1-Bulls

000004-Kevin-Durant-35-Thunders
```

Then the out put on my datafridview should be like this

```
PlayerID | Name    |  LastName    |    Number      |     Team     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
000001   |Kobe     |  Bryant      | 24             |Lakers        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
000002   |Lebron   | James        | 23             |Cavaliers     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
000003   |Derick   |Rose          | 1              |Bulls         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
000004   |Kevin    |Durant        |35              |Thunders      |
```

I cant put image thats why just draw a datagridview.

Here is the code that i am using

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String delimitedText = richTextBox1.Text;
        string[] holder = Regex.Split(richTextBox1.Text, "-");

        // Populating into datagrid

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = holder[0].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = holder[1].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = holder[2].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = holder[3].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = holder[4].ToString();
    }
```

it is just saving the first line.

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: Do some effort also. Provide some of your code.

Comment: loop your richtextbox line by line.. [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251536/from-richtextbox-to-text-files-line-after-line) how too loop richtextbox

Answer (score 1):

Use the C# Split option to get the delimited strings in an array and then populate it into a data grid.

Example:

```
String delimitedText = "000001-Kobe-Bryant-24-Lakers";
string[] stringObjects = delimitedText.Split('-');

// Populating into datagrid

dataGridView1.rows[0].cells[0] = stringObjects[0];
dataGridView1.rows[0].cells[1] = stringObjects[1];
dataGridView1.rows[0].cells[2] = stringObjects[2];
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you for helping sir. but this is the code that i already using. it wasn't saving for the nextline

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
  {
    String delimitedText = richTextBox1.Lines[i];
    string[] holder = Regex.Split(delimitedText, "-");

    // Populating into datagrid
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = holder[0].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = holder[1].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = holder[2].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = holder[3].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = holder[4].ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Change this line in the above code string[] holder = Regex.Split(delimitedText, "-");

Comment: there is no error sir. it is not looping. it is just staying in the firstline

Comment: I don't know exactly if you're doing it right. Code is working fine. [Screenshot](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/440x270q90/673/W6orMQ.png)