# How to split a regex and not display text in text file in one line

Tags: c#, regex

I have two little question which I am struggling with. Both dealing with lines really.

1: How I can I place the following Regex code into a Split()?

```
Regex(@"\r\n|\n|\r", RegexOptions.Singleline)
int num = copyText.Split().Length - 1;
//copyText is a string
```

2: When I write to a text file from a rich text box, all the text in the text file is displayed on one line. How can I get the text to be displayed as it looks in the rich text box?

```
private void Write(string file, string text) {

    //Check to see if _Parsed File exists
    if (File.Exists(file)) {
        //Write to _Parsed text file
        using(StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(file)) {
            objWriter.Write(text);
            objWriter.Close();
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("No file named " + file);
    }
}


private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Replace -ing ending words to XXXXXX code goes here...


    //Write into richTextBox2
    wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + oldSummary + copyText + newSummary;
    Write(Second_File, wholeText);
    richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st problem try this:

```
int num = Regex.Split(copyText, @"\r\n|\n|\r").Count - 1;
```

See: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx)

For the 2nd one try:

```
File.WriteAllLines(FileName, richTextBox.Lines);
```

And please read possible dublicate: [From RichTextBox to text files, line after line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251536/from-richtextbox-to-text-files-line-after-line)

`RichTextBox.SaveFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType);` built-in function

Comment: Is it ok if you show me for second answer on where I should place this in my code? I can't seem to find a right place for it.

Comment: Please see my other answer for details, because I couldn't rewrite the methods in this comment

Answer (score 0):

1: I suggest:

```
int num = copyText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
StringSplitOptions.None).Count();
```

2: Make sure richtextbox1.MultiLine is set to true

Comment: Hello, multiLine was already set to true and when I try the Environment.NewLine, it returns only one line when in fact there is 5 in the text box. I'm assuming because it is still showing one line in text file that, that is the reason it is only showing the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

### 1st option

I'd rewrite the Write method like this:

```
private void Write(string file, RichTextBox box)
{
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, box.Lines);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No file named " + file);
    }
}
```

---

### 2nd option

```
private void Write(string file, RichTextBox box)
{
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(file);
        for (int i = 0; i < box.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(box.Lines[i]);
        }
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No file named " + file);
    }
}
```

You could also try foreach if you want.

---

The 2nd option is more complicated but **better**.

And pass the RichTextBox as variable to the Write method like this:

```
Write(@"C:\path\to\file.ext", RichTextBox boxToWrite);
```